# Using Astericks to Display a Bargraph of User Inputted Numbers in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am currently attempting to solve a homework problem. The problem states to collect user inputted numbers and then arrange them using asterisks to display a graph, with the largest number having forty asterisks and the rest becoming smaller as the numbers decrease.

```
_NumberList= []
print("Please type 'quit' to stop entering numbers.")
print("Please type 'print' to view the list that has been entered so far.")
a= True
while a:
    _number= input("Please enter a number or make a selection. ")
    if _number.isdigit():
        _number=int(_number)
        _NumberList.append(_number)
    elif _number.isalpha():
        _number= _number.lower()
        if _number== 'quit':
            a= False
        if _number== 'print':
            print(_NumberList)
        else:
            print("Please use digits to enter a number.")
            print("For exmaple: 'ten' should be typed at '10'")
    else:
        print("Invalid entry.")
_NumberList.remove(max(_NumberList))
for i in range(len(_NumberList)):
    _NumberList.remove(max(_NumberList))
```

However, I am unsure as to how to find the given proportions utilizing the numerical data. Thus far, I have considered utilizing the .pop function, but it simply isn't making a ton of sense so far. I considered making them go up by one step, but again, that doesn't seem logical, and the program can run for more than forty numbers. I know I will need to utilize a loop, hence the for loop at the end, but I'm not sure as to how to continue from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable name `_NumberList` makes my eyes hurt, so I'll call it `number_list`

```
largest_number = max(number_list)
scale_factor = 40 / largest_number
scaled_number_list = [int(x * scale_factor) for x in number_list]
for scaled_number in scaled_number_list:
    print('*' * scaled_number)
```

Comment: For some reason, when I attempt to use that piece of code, it provides an error message saying it cannot multiply with the asterisk. It gives me this error message: "builtins.TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'"